# Python: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm moving over to Python from Matlab, so I'm only new to Python yet. I'm trying to create a basic piece of code for some data analysis. It should read in all the .txt datafiles in a specified directory and label them with the name of the actual .txt file. I've managed to find a way to get this working using a dictionary, but if there's a better way I'd be very grateful to hear it.

Once I have access to the data I then want to create a new list with manipulated versions of that data. To do this I want to create a new n x m list, or array, however I can't find how to correctly initialise such a list. My latest effort results in the following error:

list indices must be integers, not tuple

The code is as follows:

```
import sys
import os
import re
import string
from numpy import *

listing = os.listdir(path)
dic = {}    # define a dictionary to map the datafiles to while maintaining their filename

for filename in listing:
        match = re.findall(r'[\w.]+\.txt', filename)    # Use a regular expression findall function to identify all .txt files
        if match:
            dic[match.pop()[:-4]] = loadtxt(filename)   # Drop the .txt and assign the datafile its original name

E = []
E[:,0] = dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,0]
E[:,1] = dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,1]
E[:,2] = abs(dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,4]+dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,7]*1j)**2
E[:,3] = abs(dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,5]+dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,8]*1j)**2
E[:,4] = abs(dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,6]+dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,9]*1j)**2
```

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: In future, please include a *full* traceback for errors in python code, so we do not have to guess where your error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You are using extended slicing syntax, which only the `numpy` library supports, on the standard Python `list` type (your `E`) variable.

You'll have to use `E.append()` to add new values to it instead:

```
E.append(dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,0])
```

or simply define the whole list as a set of expressions:

```
E = [
    dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,0]
    dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,1]
    abs(dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,4]+dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,7]*1j)**2
    abs(dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,5]+dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,8]*1j)**2
    abs(dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,6]+dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][:,9]*1j)**2
]
```

or use a `numpy` array instead.

Standard python sequence types such as `str`, `list` and `tuple` only support simple indexing:

```
E[0]
E[-2]
```

or plain slicing:

```
E[:10]
E[1:2]
E[3:]
E[:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful and also made me aware that I should possibly be consulting more the numpy documentation for the type work I'll do doing as opposed to just searching under Python. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can specify only one index for an array.
 Use someting like this
`E.append(dic['Test_Efield_100GHz'][0])`
This will store E[0] as an array whose values can be accessed s by E[0][i] where i is the column name
Note: Python does not have matrix type data structure, it only has arrays.Matrix is just a array of arrays.